# Alternative to datetime-local

Tags: html

Is there an alternative for that because Firefox and Internet Explorer are not supporting it...

Example:

```
<form>
<input type="datetime-local">
</form>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use `<input type="date"> <input type="time">` together. Personally I think this is why datetime-local was removed. There are some great polyfills as well, like this one: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html

Comment: But when I checked here it wasn't supported the the broswer: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: Right. A couple things: 1) w3schools has a pretty bad rep these days (see http://www.w3fools.com/). 2) You can always use caniuse.com to get better browser support info (http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). 3) If something is _not_ supported (date types in forms are pretty sketchy still), always look for a polyfill like the one I linked above (http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html), as they're designed to give you support for such features while still working natively when they are supported. The one above has really good support, and is only called when needed.

Comment: Thanks I will put that in my favourite

Comment: I just tried to use the type="date" and type="time" both are not working.

Comment: Again, you'll have to try the polyfill if you are using a browser that doesn't support it. It has to be configured a bit.

Comment: I used the pattern as an alternative.

Comment: I don't see any indication that "datetime-local" was removed. Do you have a source for that? It's in the spec: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#local-date-and-time-state-(type=datetime-local)

Comment: @ccnokes at the time this was accurate but it's not anymore. See https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/59541 for context on that. Clearly it has been put back since then, as you say it is in the spec. I'm not sure when that happened though.

Answer (score 3):

I ran across this while looking for something to use instead of `datetime-local`

https://www.daterangepicker.com/

It has similar functionality to `datetime-local` and some extra.  The one thing you would have to account for is being able to limit users' changing the date values in the input box if you do it that way.  `datetime-local` automatically prevents say, putting letters into the time values.

Otherwise, Jonathan's answer still seems the best basic built-in option that works with FF/Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

In my case,  I tried many things but nothing looks perfect, finally, I came with this walk around to split the datetime into two inline  inputs and remove the border between them to looks like just one input variable:

```
<form action="" class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" style=" border-right-style: none" type="date" max="9999-12-12T00:00:00.00" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" style=" border-left-style: none" type="time" max="9999-12-12T00:00:00.00" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

By my side I'm using a class (datetime-local) on all the inputs with type **datetime-local**.
Then I can replace all these inputs by a custome version: **CalendarPopup** (https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/calendar-popup/)

`var calendar = $('input.datetime-local').CalendarPopup();`

Answer (score -1):

Currently we have many alternatives for a `date` and `time` inputs, on a quick search, `type="time"` and `type="date"` is not supported on the latest safary version.

I take this list from an admin dashboard theme:

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

https://github.com/T00rk/bootstrap-material-datetimepicker

http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/

http://www.daterangepicker.com/

https://fullcalendar.io/

https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/andchir/datetime-polyfill

```
<script src="datetime-polyfill.js"></script>
```